# Spinner is rendered differently on API 16 and on API 21

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-xml, android-styles

I am trying to inject some views into a linear layout at runtime, with a button click.

My test enviornment being API 21 and API 16. FOr API 21 everything seems fine I get the material spinner. While testing on API 16 I get the Material spinner for all views defined in XML, however when I use the following method to generate and inject a sinner dynamically I get the API level 16 spinner.

Code:

```
 public void addView(LinearLayout container, String[] spin_array, String hint, int inputType, int tagger) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_company_fragment_two_dynamic_content, null);

        final Spinner spin_dynamic = (Spinner) addView.findViewById(R.id.email_spinner1);
        EditText edt_dynamic = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_email1);
        ImageView remove_dynamic = (ImageView) addView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);


        edt_dynamic.setHint(hint);
        setUpSpinners(spin_array, spin_dynamic);
        edt_dynamic.setTag(container.getTag() + "edt" + tagger);
        edt_dynamic.setInputType(inputType);
        edt_dynamic.setTypeface(roboto_condenced_light);
        spin_dynamic.setTag(container.getTag() + "spin" + tagger);

        idsMap.put(spin_dynamic.getTag().toString(), edt_dynamic.getTag().toString());

        // get height from dimens
        int height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.lin_height);
        // set this height
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);

        // we are only concerned about top margin here.
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.topMargin), 0, 0);
        container.addView(addView, 1, layoutParams);

        remove_dynamic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Remove View (LinearLayout) and also remove the key from idsMap so that we dont get a NullPointer later
                ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                idsMap.remove(spin_dynamic.getTag().toString());
            }
        });
    }


 public void setUpSpinners(String[] spin_array, Spinner spin) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spin_array);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The XML file `add_company_fragment_two_dynamic_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sub_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_linear"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/email_spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view31"
        android:layout_width="0.3dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#D3D3D3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_email1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_remove"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/close_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Screen grab:

[image]

Here is the `styles.xml` entry for this Activity:

```
<style name="CompanyPagerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#adadad</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#adadad</item>
    </style>
```

Here is my `Gradle` entry:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

What do I miss here? I also find that ripple is not working below API 21

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to go and redesign the whole view.